# Using variable in subprocess curl

Tags: python, json, curl, subprocess

I am aware there exists questions answered on this but I wanted to ask as it is different from the rest.

I am trying to send a curl request using subprocess and cannot get a variable to funcion:

```
 config = json.loads(open('/etc/config.json').read())
    endpoint = config["end_point"]
    auth = config["auth_token"]
    config["widgets"]



    #Send using subprocess
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call([
    'curl',
    '-X',
    'POST',
    '-H',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    '-d',
    '{ "auth_token": **'auth'**, "widget": "329bdbea887ad8e10e4e496f7a60f898", "title": "Something", "items":[{"label": "testR", "value": "$999.99"}, {"label": "testB", "value": "$9,001.00"}] }',
    **'endpoint'**
```

The config file contains the following:

```
{"end_point":"http://domain.com","auth_token":"e91a0ffe758c19=ed0","widgets":{"host_info":"fd8a63ads499289a312","memory_info":"0bc2c24ds28bc4c507ad","cpu_info":"5assd0dc41dbd73681"}}
```

Neither auth not endpointurl is not working.

Full code is:

import subprocess
subprocess.call([
    'curl',
    '-X',
    'POST',
    '-H',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    '-d',
    '{ "auth_token": "e91a0ffe758c194896eb4daed0", "widget": "329bdbea887ad8496f7a60f898", "title": "Something", "items":[{"label": "text2, "value": "$999.99"}, {"label": "text1", "value": "$9,001.00"}] }',
    'http://domain.com'
    ])

I

Here I am trying to use **auth** variable instead of **"e91a0ffe758c194896eb4daed0"**

Comment: Are you getting any error?  Certainly you must be, or the code got pasted incorrectly.

Comment: @jedwards I`m not getting any error.  and @KarolyHorvath print auth in this will not work.

Comment: `**auth = config["auth_token"]**` is not valid Python syntax

Comment: @PatrickCollins it was the "BOLD" character on Stackoverflow. Now fixed. Any ideas how I can use the variable in subprocess?

Comment: @user2843053: `**'auth'**` is also not valid -- "**" is a meaningful sequence of characters, be careful not to use it in your code. Is that also intended to be bold?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
config["widgets"]
```

isn't doing anything, it's not clear what you want here. As far as I can tell, what you mean by:

```
'{ "auth_token": 'auth', "widget": "329bdbea887ad8e10e4e496f7a60f898", "title": "Something", "items":[{"label": "testR", "value": "$999.99"}, {"label": "testB", "value": "$9,001.00"}] }',
```

is to pass some JSON to cURL inside of a string. What you're looking for, then, is:

```
'{ "auth_token": "%s", "widget": "329bdbea887ad8e10e4e496f7a60f898", "title": "Something", "items":[{"label": "testR", "value": "$999.99"}, {"label": "testB", "value": "$9,001.00"}] }' % auth
```

Also, `'endpoint'` means 'the string containing the characters 'e', 'n', 'd', 'p', 'o', 'i', 'n', 't', not your variable, `endpoint`. You probably just want to drop the quotes there. You haven't pasted all of your code -- seeing as the parentheses are unbalanced -- so we can't be sure of what's going on, but that's probably a start.

EDIT: Try again, I made a mistake -- `string.format` won't work because of the `{}` characters inside your string. Use the corrected `%` solution above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry if it is not clear. Let me explain you once again in case you have doubts. What i want is basicly pass a variable in this case "auth" inside the subprocess.call. "auth_token": "{}", is not doing it for me for the values are inside '.  How can I assign auth to "auth_token" value in the subprocess call?

Comment: Please post the full code that you are attempting to use in your question.

Comment: What error are you getting when you try the code that I just posted?

Comment: What is the value you're expecting? What is the value you're getting?

Comment: The value I am expecting should be the value of auth, thats clear: 
@peter check here: http://pastebin.com/W46D4i0R